# Javascript Event Listeners with tooltips

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use a javascript event listener to initialize a tool tip for a button who is the target for the listener? I have searched online and found many ways to make a tool tip work but would like to make use of an event listener. I'm going to use onmoveover as the type of event for the target. Is this really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Google should give you many examples, here's one...

http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/

Comment: I saw that implementation. it isn't so simple but thanks for confirming that it is possible. Was a little skeptical

Comment: You didn't ask if it was 'simple', you asked if it was 'possible' :) :)